# v.dissolve to multipolygon

Tags: geoprocessing, grass-gis, dissolve

Using v.dissolve in GRASS, I'd like to get a multipolyon as a result. However, I end up with distinct polygons with the same 'dissolve value.'

For example; lets assume I have two polygon features which are not touching each other spatially. Both have a 'DISS" value of 1. If I run v.dissolve on this DISS value, I get the same thing in the output as the input (i.e. two seperate polygons with a DISS value of 1). What I would like to be able to get is an output that contains one single multipolygon. How do I go about this?

Comment: Please also say which GRASS GIS version you use...

Comment: Thanks markus; I am using GRASS 6.4.3RC1 (2012) via qgis/OSGeo4W

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like GRASS does in fact treat the result as a multipolygon, although QGIS displays it as separate features. I determined this by calculating the area on the feature(s) and they all came out to be the same for each DISS value.  This is also hinted at in [this post](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2006-October/000680.html), where Radim responds:

> The multi features are kept in GRASS but in QGIS represented as
>   multiple features.